# Deleting objects from a Queue/List before/after removing them?

Tags: c#, list, queue

I want to be sure no memory leaks are present in my program. If I delete an object from an array like structure, is it automatically removed from the list or remain as a null object? Do I first dequeue and then delete, or delete and then dequeue?

Comment: Could you provide the relevant code, please?

Comment: There´s no such thing as a null-object in .NET. Any object to which there are no further references is garbage-collected automatically sooner or earlier. No need to think about that too much. That´s the entire point of a **managed** language like C#.

Comment: @HimBromBeere There's something to take into consideration, in order for objects to be garbage-collected easily, they must be in a state that they can be, that usually means closing connections and disposing objects that take too much memory.